# How do I retrieve a record by ID from an Active Record record collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a collection of records returned from an Active Record query, how can I access one of those records if I know its ID?

Comment: Yes, you surely can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. Assuming you have an ActiveRecord relation called `records` and are searching for `id`:

1. You can use the [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) method, but this will result in another call to the database:

   `records.find(id)`
2. You can search through the collection without using the database by calling Ruby's [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) method as follows:

   `records.find { |r| r.id == id }`

Although they share the same name, we are invoking two different `find` methods in the above example. The first will use more database resources, while the latter will use more application server resources.  I am not sure which one is faster in the end.

Comment: I would add that despite having the same name 1 is [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) and the later is [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

Answer (score 1):

```
TableName.find(id)
```

should do it.

Or if you already have a bunch of records in an Active Record query you can pull out the one with the known id like:

```
active_record_query = User.where(first_name: "Jim")
record = active_record_query.where(id: record_id).first
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing I have a result set of users and I want to find the user with ID = 3 in that set:

```
foo = User.all
user3 = foo.find {|x| x.id == 3}
```

Of course if you know the ID, you could just find it. Supposing I have a users table and I know the ID of the user I want is 3:

```
user3 = User.find(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find records with from the database with [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find).

`Thing.find(1)` will query the database for `SELECT things.* FROM things WHERE things.id = 1`. And raise an `ActiveRecord::NotFoundError` if the record cannot be found. Find can also be used with a list of ids.

If you have a relation that is already loaded from the database you would use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) or its alias `#detect`. ActiveRecord::Relation includes Enumerable so it works even if you don't explicitly cast to an array with `.to_a`.

> Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block
>   is not false. If no object matches, calls ifnone and returns its
>   result when it is specified, or returns nil otherwise.

Example:

```
[1,2,3,4].find(&:even?) # => 2
User.all.load.find { |u| u.id == 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the find method.

```
# Assuming you were retrieving an ActiveRecordRelation s
s = MyRecord.where(name: "test")
s.find(id)
```

For further information see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find